# How to get a plot out of LuxPy package

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot the color-rendering information for a given spectrum using the `lx.cri.plot_cri_graphics(SPD)` function of the [LuxPy package](https://ksmet1977.github.io/luxpy/build/html/index.html#).

There is the following example code on [page 17 of this official tutorial](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/15502724.2018.1518717) which passes a predefined spectrum (SPD) to the mentioned function.

"*The LuxPy.cri subpackage also supports a function that
[...] provides TM30-like graphical output. For example, the code below generates the output in Fig. 7*"

```
import luxpy as lx

SPD = lx._CIE_ILLUMINANTS['F4']
data,_,_ = lx.cri.plot_cri_graphics(SPD)
```

Figure 7:

[image: Figure 7]

In my case, the program just finishes without plot, errors or terminal output.

The `data` object in the above example contains a bunch of data and is of type `dict`, but no plot appears and the script just finishes. Many of the package's classes have dedicated `.plot()` member functions, which - for my understanding - should all work the same way. But I do not get any plots popping up for any of those either (like I'm used to from working with Matplotlib).

Is there anything I need to do beside calling the `.plot_cri_graphics()` funtions? Something that may be self-explanatory for someone more experienced?
Do I have to pass `data` to another plot funtion to actually get a plot output?

Comment: what if you add a `plt.show()` at the end of your code?

Comment: @Stef exactly, I found that out by accident. Feel free to add this as an answer so I accept it. Otherwise I'll do it myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official tutorial uses IPython with inline plotting (see section 5.1: `%matplotlib inline`, see [Plotting](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html#id1) for details). If you run the example as plain python file, you'll need to add `plt.show()` at the end to actually show the plot.